# Central limit theorem in a multidimensional sphere

Tags: central-limit-theorem, importance-sampling

In the book of David MacKay there's a chapter on Monte Carlo methods (http://www.inference.org.uk/mackay/erice.pdf) where, when discussing the importance sampling, it gives this example:

Suppose a multidimensional sphere:

$$P^{*}(\mathbf{x})=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}{1} & {0 \leq \rho(\mathbf{x}) \leq R_{P}} \\ {0} & {\rho(\mathbf{x})>R_{P}}\end{array}\right.$$

with $\rho(\mathbf{x}) \equiv\left(\sum_{i} x_{i}^{2}\right)^{1/2}$ and a proposed distribution density that is a Gaussian centered in the origin like

$$Q(\mathbf{x})=\prod_{i} \operatorname{Normal}\left(x_{i} ; 0, \sigma^{2}\right)$$

Then, he claims that if $\rho$ is the distance from the origin to some sample of $Q$, then, by central limit theorem, $\rho^2$ has a distribution with mean and std going like

$$\rho^{2} \sim N \sigma^{2} \pm \sqrt{2 N} \sigma^{2}$$

I honestly can't see this exactly. I see $\rho^2$ is a sum of iid squared variables that, with many of them, tends to the Gaussian. But shouldn't the mean be 0? And why do you have a factor of $\sqrt{2}$ in the std?

Comment: Pick an $i.$  Compute the mean and standard deviation of $x_i^2.$  Apply the CLT.

Comment: I am a bit confused... maybe it is due to the fact that I don't know anything about importance sampling but there is no obvious relation between $Q$ and $P^*$, right? I.e. $Q$ distributes points also outside of the sphere... That said the mean of $\rho^2$ is just $\sum_i E[X_i^2]$ and $\sigma^2 = \text{Var}(X_i) = E[X_i^2] - E[X_i]^2 = E[X_i^2]$ or do I misread something ?